# how to deal with Days and/or month with one digit (remove the 0) in R

Tags: r, date, format

I'm getting my current date with the format I want using this code:

```
format(Sys.Date(),"%m-%d-%Y")
#[1] "06-26-2015"
```

However, I would like to have it as:

```
"6-26-2015"
```

How can I discard the 0 when a day or a month is only one digit?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could just extract each element of the date as numeric and format it however you want.

```
library(lubridate)

d <- Sys.Date()
paste(month(d), day(d), year(d), sep="-")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 gsub('(?<=\\b|-)0', '', v1, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "6-26-2015" "6-5-2015"  "11-5-2000"
```

Or

```
 do.call(paste, c(read.table(text=v1, sep="-"), sep="-"))
 #[1] "6-26-2015" "6-5-2015"  "11-5-2000"
```

#### Update

If we include dates with year < 1000, and needs to remove the leading zero only for 'day' and 'month'

```
 gsub('^\\b0?([^-]+-)0?', '\\1', v2, perl=TRUE)
 #[1] "6-26-2015" "6-5-2015"  "12-8-0940" "11-5-2000" "1-4-0001"
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c("06-26-2015", "06-05-2015", "11-05-2000")
 v2 <- c("06-26-2015", "06-05-2015", "12-08-0940", "11-05-2000", "01-04-0001")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative which doesn't rely on using `gsub` to alter a string representation of the date:

```
l <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
curr.date <- paste(l$mday, l$mon+1, l$year+1900, sep="-")
```

**Output:**

```
> curr.date
[1] "26-6-2015"
```

Comment: It is conceptually complex to conditionally remove zeroes from a date string _only_ when they appear in the day or month and only when they prefix these numbers.  It seemed easier to just extract out the pieces of the date in the format the OP wants and then `paste()` them together.

Comment: I removed my "error prone" comment, but you were probably spot-on when you originally said that he should keep the date in the format which is outputted to ensure conversion back is possible.

Comment: Yes, I had seen questions, where they want to format it to 2 digit format from this output

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another solution: Mark the day and the month with an "X", remove any occurrence of "X0", and finally clean up by removing any residual "X".

```
gsub("X","",gsub("X0","", format(Sys.Date(),"X%m-X%d-%Y")))
#[1] "6-26-2015"
```